# What is the derivative of the ReLU activation function?

Tags: self-study, neural-networks

What is the derivative of the ReLU activation function defined as:

$$ \mathrm{ReLU}(x) = \mathrm{max}(0, x)$$

What about the special case where there is a discontinuity in the function at $x=0$?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The derivative is:

$$ f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if  }  x < 0 \\
1 & \text{if  }  x > 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

And undefined in $x=0$.

The reason for it being undefined at $x=0$ is that its left- and [right derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability) are not equal.

Comment: So in practice (implementation), one just picks either $0$ or $1$ for the $x=0$ case?

Comment: The convention is that drdx=1(x>0)

Comment: @TomHale by the way, see Nouroz Rahman's answer at https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-compute-the-gradient-of-a-ReLU-for-backpropagation: _"[...] In my view, in built-in library functions (for example: `tf.nn.relu()`) derivative at x = 0 is taken zero to ensure a sparser matrix..."_